# How to wait for multiple Tasks without blocking the GUI?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

In a C# .NET 4.0 Windows Forms GUI application, in response to a button being clicked I need to spawn a large number of processes and show them in a list box. As each process ends it should be removed from the list and when all processes are done, something should happen.

Since it's 4.0 I think using `Task` is the best route but I can't just run up a bunch of tasks and call `Task.WaitAll` because that would block the main UI thread, as the button click handler wouldn't return.

What is the nicest way to implement this? I can see two main options:

1. The button handler starts one task, which runs all the other tasks and waits for them to complete.
2. I don't use `Task.WaitAll` - as each Task completes it checks (or tells the application to check) if all the tasks are complete or not.

But is there a standard/preferred solution here using the TPL?

Also - can a `Task` update my form GUI or do I need to decouple Task-GUI interaction, e.g. when a `Task` completes it fires an event on the `Form`?

Pseudo-code would be great - I'm new to TPL and much of the fun stuff available in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you were using .NET 4.5 you would use something like `await Task.WhenAll(...)`. It can handle `IEnumerable<Task>`, `Task[]` and also `IEnumerable<Task<TResult>>`.

If there is no way you can use .NET 4.5, you can come up with a solution of yourself, that will involve Task.ContinueWith and a counter of how many tasks are left to run, that is updated using `Interlocked.Decrement`. Also, you can look at how it's done inside .NET 4.5 by looking at this source. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,69351c6da968e5d1. It's a bit lengthy, but it basically is what I said: tasks are continued with some other tasks that update internal counter.

Comment: .NET 4.0 has no `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: I am not sure if 4.5 would be OK but I'd be interested to see a more thorough answer if it's a good way to solve the problem.

Comment: If you need .NET 4.0 instead of 4.5, the Microsoft.Bcl.Async NuGet package is supposed to provide `TaskEx.WhenAll` (but verification that it is indeed available would be nice).